# Offline integration/communication using flutter and R language?

Tags: r, flutter, dart, integration

I need to create a integration between a Flutter Application and a statistical language R.

We are developing a students test Flutter application that also works offline too, and we need to make some how a way that flutter application connects with an R application and receive some information, like the next question for the student to answer.

We will create a API that the flutter application can communicate when connected at internet. But when not, we need to execute or emulate that R application on a mobile app.

We have no ideias how to make this for offline mode and we need some help, to see if this is viable.

Comment: You had me until *"emulate R"*. Good luck with that, I think that developing this for two languages simultaneously is a *lot* of work and overhead. Knowing as much as we do about the content being used here (i.e., *nothing*), it's hard to say. Is it deterministic or stochastic? Is it from a known set of data? Can the flutter app, starting in a known state, pre-query the API for things needed when offline? Do you need to store the students' reactions/results/answers and upload when able?

Comment: Well, R can be installed on Android using GNURoot Debian. https://selbydavid.com/2017/12/29/r-android/. Connecting it with Flutter, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Well i guess that you can go around with writing your r code in python and then integrate it in flutter
For python-r integration you can use:
rpy2 library
And for flutter python integration you can use:
dartpy library

But i wouldn't recommend..
Its very beta and its too much to go through to making this bridge.
I would recommend if just need a t.test to use python library sciki-learn there's alot of statistic there
Anyway good luck:) !